# How to unify multiple columns in pandas dataframe into a multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [1,2], "b": [3,4], "c": [5,6]}, index=[0,1])
```

In tabular form:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

I want to transform it to a dataframe like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={"foo":[1,2,3,4,5,6]},
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
               [('a', 0), ('a', 1), ('b', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 0), ('c', 1)],
               names=("var", "id")))
```

tabular form:

```
         foo
var id     
a   0      1
    1      2
b   0      3
    1      4
c   0      5
    1      6
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `unstack`

```
out = df.unstack().to_frame('foo')
Out[146]: 
     foo
a 0    1
  1    2
b 0    3
  1    4
c 0    5
  1    6
```

Comment: wow much better than mine

Comment: @Umar.H yours good as well ~ :-)

Answer (score 2):

First create a new multiindex

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.tolist(), ['foo']])

print(df)

    a   b   c
  foo foo foo
0   1   3   5
1   2   4   6
```

then use `.stack` with `.swaplevel()`

```
df.stack(0).swaplevel(0,1)
```

---

```
     foo
a 0    1
b 0    3
c 0    5
a 1    2
b 1    4
c 1    6
```